# Why does SonarQube raise a MISRA-C critical remark <<Function names should be used either as a call [...]>> on the "startup" code for ARM Cortex-M3?

Tags: c, arm, sonarqube, cortex-m, misra

#### Generic description

I encountered the following SonarQube remark (MISRA-C:2012), while implementing the startup code in C, for an ARM Cortex-M3:

> *Function names should be used either as a call with a parameter list or with the "&" operator*

with the following description:

> *Using a "bald" function name is likely a bug. Rather than testing the return value of a function with a void parameter list, it implicitly retrieves the address of that function in memory. If that's truly what's intended, then it should be made explicit with the use of the & (address-of) operator. If it's not, then a parameter list (even an empty one) should be added after the function name.*

I am using the following compiler:

> *armclang V6.12, with Language C99*

The version of the SonarQube is:

> *Version 6.7 (build 33306)*

**The SonarQube remark is raised on the Reference of *Reset_Handler* inside the Vector Table array. (see the code below)**

#### The basic code that was scanned:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Exception / Interrupt Handler Function Prototype
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
typedef void (*pFunc)(void);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  External References
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
extern uint32_t __INITIAL_SP;

extern __NO_RETURN void __PROGRAM_START(void);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Internal References
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
__NO_RETURN void Default_Handler(void);
__NO_RETURN void Reset_Handler(void);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Exception / Interrupt Handler
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exceptions */
void NMI_Handler            (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void HardFault_Handler      (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void MemManage_Handler      (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void BusFault_Handler       (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void UsageFault_Handler     (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void SVC_Handler            (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void DebugMon_Handler       (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void PendSV_Handler         (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
void SysTick_Handler        (void) __attribute__ ((weak, alias("Default_Handler")));
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Exception / Interrupt Vector table
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

extern const pFunc __VECTOR_TABLE[16];
       const pFunc __VECTOR_TABLE[16] __VECTOR_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE = {
  (pFunc)(&__INITIAL_SP),                   /*     Initial Stack Pointer */
  Reset_Handler,                            /*     Reset Handler <<<<<------ WHERE THE SONARQUBE REMARK IS */
  NMI_Handler,                              /* -14 NMI Handler */
  HardFault_Handler,                        /* -13 Hard Fault Handler */
  MemManage_Handler,                        /* -12 MPU Fault Handler */
  BusFault_Handler,                         /* -11 Bus Fault Handler */
  UsageFault_Handler,                       /* -10 Usage Fault Handler */
  0,                                        /*     Reserved */
  0,                                        /*     Reserved */
  0,                                        /*     Reserved */
  0,                                        /*     Reserved */
  SVC_Handler,                              /*  -5 SVCall Handler */
  DebugMon_Handler,                         /*  -4 Debug Monitor Handler */
  0,                                        /*     Reserved */
  PendSV_Handler,                           /*  -2 PendSV Handler */
  SysTick_Handler,                          /*  -1 SysTick Handler */
};

void Reset_Handler(void)
{
    SystemInit(); // CMSIS System Initialization
    __PROGRAM_START(); // Enter PreMain (C library entry point)
}

void Default_Handler(void)
{
    while (1) {
        __asm volatile(""); /* this line is considered to have side-effects */
    }
}
```

#### The basic problem

I don't really understand why it complains at that particular point, and I don't really see what am I missing:
    - the function pointer is defined at the beginning *pFunc*
    - the return type is defined as *void*, and also there are no parameters for the functions
    - the type of the Vector Table array is "pFunc"
    - both the *Default_Handler*, as well as the *Reset_Handler* match the correct prototype as defined by the function pointer

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Thank you.

#### Later edit

@Lundin I found the following example of non-compliant code:

```
int func(void) {
  // ...
}

void f2(int a, int b) {
  // ...
  if (func) {  // Noncompliant - tests that the memory address of func() is non-null
    //...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Compliant code:

```
void f2(int a, int b) {
  // ...
  if (func()) {  // tests that the return value of func() > 0
    //...
  }
  // ...
}
```

So you seem to be right. The tool thinks is a different issue.

Comment: I think it wants you to use the `&` address-of operator when dealing with using it as a function pointer.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianGibbons. You are right. As "dbush" explained, apparently the SonarQube complains because it expects for me to call those functions, but I only need to save the addresses of the Handlers in the Interrupt Vector, but NOT call them explicitly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MISRA-C, which rule does the tool claim that the code violates, more exactly? This is just a false positive, a.k.a. tool bug. It may however be caused by the tool not recognizing non-standard C such as `__attribute__`

Comment: @Lundin: thank you for your answer. Hmm, honestly after further checking, it could be a false-flag...the rule appears to be the following "MISRA C:2004, 16.9 - A function identifier shall only be used with either a preceding &, or with a parenthesized parameter list, which may be empty. ". But this refers to something else. The idea is that the code deals with the Vector table, where I don't call explicitly any function, just store the addresses.

Comment: @AlexAn So why did you write MISRA-C:2012? That rule doesn't exist in MISRA-C:2012. And even in 2004 I don't think the intention was to block it from being used in initializer lists, just from doing stuff like `if(f)` which could be a bug when the programmer actually meant `if(f())`.

Comment: @Lundin well, I wrote initially that because our Sonarqube setup uses the MISRA-C:2012, but because the tool did not give a specific rule number, all I could find was the reference rule as it appears in the MISRA C:2004. This was just to help people find the actual rule number in anyone of the standards. I know it was a little messy, but I did not know how to give the relevant information the best. And yes, it appears that the tool refers exactly to what you mentioned.

Comment: @Lundin, I added a new edit in the description, that I found later. I am not very familiar with Sonarqube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SonarQube warning is complaining that you're using the name of a function without calling it, suspecting that you meant to actually call it.

Because a function name is automatically converted to a pointer to a function, `func` and `&func` refer to the same thing, so you can use them interchangeably.

Since you're not attempting to call the functions but are instead putting their addresses in an array, use the address-of operator to make it explicit that you want to take the address of the function instead of calling it, along with any other function pointers.

```
extern const pFunc __VECTOR_TABLE[16];
       const pFunc __VECTOR_TABLE[16] __VECTOR_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE = {
  (pFunc)(&__INITIAL_SP),                    /*     Initial Stack Pointer */
  &Reset_Handler,                            /*     Reset Handler */
  &NMI_Handler,                              /* -14 NMI Handler */
  &HardFault_Handler,                        /* -13 Hard Fault Handler */
  &MemManage_Handler,                        /* -12 MPU Fault Handler */
  &BusFault_Handler,                         /* -11 Bus Fault Handler */
  &UsageFault_Handler,                       /* -10 Usage Fault Handler */
  NULL,                                      /*     Reserved */
  NULL,                                       /*     Reserved */
  NULL,                                      /*     Reserved */
  NULL,                                      /*     Reserved */
  &SVC_Handler,                              /*  -5 SVCall Handler */
  &DebugMon_Handler,                         /*  -4 Debug Monitor Handler */
  NULL,                                      /*     Reserved */
  &PendSV_Handler,                           /*  -2 PendSV Handler */
  &SysTick_Handler,                          /*  -1 SysTick Handler */
};
```

Comment: Hi @dbush, thank you very much for your quick response. Indeed, the point is to save the addresses of the interrupt handlers in the Interrupt Vector, but I don't call them explicitly. I assume then I would get this critical remark for every one of those handlers, if I would fix them in succession. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @AlexAn Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.